# What is the bog beast in Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back called?

Tags: star-wars, luke-skywalker, the-empire-strikes-back

In *Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back*, we see R2-D2 falling into a deep bog upon Luke's arrival at Dagobah.  He is then ingested by a beast and spat out upon the shore.

In the original script, this sequence is as follows:

> Suddenly, through the thick fog layer, a dark shape appears, moving toward the little droid.  The dark, sinuous bog beast dives beneath the swampy water, making a loud clunk against Artoo's metal hull.  The droid disappears from sight, uttering a pathetic electronic scream.

http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html

In the script, the beast swallowing Artoo is called a 'bog beast.'  **Is there a more technical name for this creature, or is it only referred to as a 'bog beast?'**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That would be a Dagobahian "***[Dragonsnake](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dragonsnake/Canon)***". A detailed description of this beast can be found on the old Starwars.com site under the title "[Meet the Creatures of Dagobah](http://web.archive.org/web/20150328085609/http://www.starwars.com/news/meet-the-creatures-of-dagobah)"

> R2-D2 has a really close encounter with a dragonsnake during Luke’s
> first visit to Dagobah. These long and slender aquatic reptiles reside
> in Dagobah’s many primeval bogs. The lagoon near Yoda’s hut is even
> known (probably just by Yoda) as Dragonsnake Bog. One particular
> dragonsnake was hungry enough to devour Artoo when the droid was
> swimming to the shore. Luckily the Astromech didn’t taste very well
> and the creature spat the droid into spooky branches where he landed
> near the skeletal remains of an unknown creature. Dragonsnakes can
> also be found on Nal Hutta.
>
> [image]

Pablo Hidalgo gives us a little more info in *[Star Wars Insider #69](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_69)*.

> **Q.** In *The Empire Strikes Back*, what is that thing that swallows up R2-D2 on Dagobah?
>
> **PH:** That droid-gulping horror was a dragonsnake, a large omnivorous predator that lurks beneath the muddy waters of Dagobah. Because of its tendency to stay mostly submerged, it is often mistaken for a swamp slug.
>
> Only the oily, black hide of its knobby-spined back was visible in the film because that was the extent of the creature's fabrication. Without the rest of its impressive form built, the practical model used on set resembled a big bloated leech. It was was controlled by underwater divers during the shoot, and was simply referred to as the “swamp creature”

Comment: @Longshanks87 - If you found the answer helpful, don't forget to upvote and press the "accept" button on the left hand side :-)

Comment: I was just waiting to see if there would be any more answers.  But thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Longshanks87 - If you click the links above, there's loads of additional info but it all kinda points back to what I've said.